# Unziping a file and read unzipped file

Tags: c#, ssis

I am unzipping a file in SSIS using script task. And then i use this unzipped file. But when i am using this file its giving me error "[Flat File Source [644]] Error: The column data for column "No  Asks" overflowed the disk I/O buffer.
". So i think its unable to recognize the next line. As "NO Asks" is the last column.

The problem changes and works fine when i open the unzipped file manually and save it as csv. And i am surprised even the unzipped file is also csv but it doesn't work. It works only when i manually save it using save as option with .csv extension.

Comment: It sounds like the file is using non-standard end line characters.  Can you open the file in an advanced text editor to check this?

Comment: In what application are you doing 'Save As CSV'? ZIP doesn't have this option. Are you opening it in Excel?

Comment: Yeah i can open file in editor..@DataMasseur

Comment: No i am not doing save as. But i just tried that unzipped file by opening in excel and save it as csv manually. And it worked. But when i use it directlly it doesn't. Where as unzipped file is also csv but may be some formatting problem.

Comment: The suspense is killing me ... so you opened the file in an editor ... and you saw ?

Comment: Hi sorry for my bad explanation. Actually i was not able to read the unzipped file. when i opened it in editor and saved it as csv and re execute the programm (without using unzip funtion and directlly use the csv file) it was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem . i did following steps.
 1. I unzipped the file as text
 2. I took that text file as a source for the flat file source manager(As earlier i didn't because i am using connecting string as dynamically using expression. So it was not able to understand the row delimiter).
 3. Now its working very well.

Please ask me any question if its not clear